# ParseUser issue signing up (PHP SDK)

Tags: php, parse-platform

I trying to "sign up" a user in Parse with the code below. The error I am getting is below the code. This is right out of the documentation, I have never had a problem with this in Swift but this is the first time trying to work with the PHP SDK.

```js
Require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseUser; 


// Initializes with the <APPLICATION_ID>, <REST_KEY>, and <MASTER_KEY>
ParseClient::initialize( "id", "key", "master" );
ParseClient::setServerURL('https://parseapi.back4app.com/users', '/');

// Signup
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$user = ParseUser::create('_User');
$user->set("username" , $username);
$user->set("password", $password);
try {
    $user->signUp();
} catch (ParseException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
};
```

Error:

```
Parse\ParseException: [] in /Users/logankelly/workstation/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php:604 Stack trace: #0 /Users/logankelly/workstation/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php(1238): Parse\ParseClient::_request('POST', 'classes/_User', NULL, '{"username":"lo...', false) #1 /Users/logankelly/workstation/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php(1148): Parse\ParseObject::deepSave(Object(Parse\ParseUser), false) #2 /Users/logankelly/workstation/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseUser.php(122): Parse\ParseObject->save() #3 /Users/logankelly/workstation/signup.php(24): Parse\ParseUser->signUp() #4 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```php
Require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseException;

ParseClient::initialize("appId", "restKey", "masterKey" );
ParseClient::setServerURL('https://parseapi.back4app.com', '/');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$user = new ParseUser();
$user->set("username", $username);
$user->set("password", $password);

try {
  $user->signUp();
} catch (ParseException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the error I got when I did this, I have been searching for what these errors mean and haven't found anything.

Comment: Parse\ParseException: [] in /Users/logankelly/workstation/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php:604 Stack trace: #0 /Users/logankelly/workstation/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php(1238): Parse\ParseClient::_request('POST', 'classes/_User', NULL, '{"username":"lo...', false) #1 /Users/logankelly/workstation/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php(1148):

Comment: Parse\ParseObject::deepSave(Object(Parse\ParseUser), false) #2 /Users/logankelly/workstation/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseUser.php(122): Parse\ParseObject->save() #3 /Users/logankelly/workstation/signup.php(25): Parse\ParseUser->signUp() #4 {main}

Comment: I've just run the code and it worked perfectly for me. What is the version of the sdk and parse server that you are using?

Comment: I am using the Parse Server: 3.10.0 SDK 1.4.*

Comment: Could you please try to upgrade the PHP SDK to the latest version? 1.6.0